# Why one independent variable gets dropped in SPSS multiple regression?

Tags: linear-regression, logistic-regression, spss

I was running a linear multiple regression as well as a logistic multiple regression in SPSS.

After that when looking at the results, I realised that in each regression, one independent variable was automatically excluded by SPSS. Did we do something wrong here or what do we have to do in order to have all independent variables included in the regression?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you say more about what the variable represented?  Usually when this happens it's because you have entered a set of indicator (aka "dummy") variables for a given set of mutually exclusive levels of a categorical variable.  E.g. you might have a categorical variable for age, and have then entered indicators for "18 or younger" and "19 or older."  SPSS will automatically drop one indicator from the set; that "level" of the category then becomes the default for the regression.  If you include a constant (y-intercept) in the model, the default level will become part of the constant.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer. Yes, I think this might have happened here. So in the dataset, I am categorizing tweets based on added media. So the categories are "photo", "video" or "animated_gif", if none of these are true it will be categorized as "text". So I think this is the flaw right?

Comment: Yes, if you're entering indicators for all four of those possibilities, SPSS will drop one of them automatically.  For your use case, I'd recommend not entering the indicator for "text" since that's the default, and you'd then be able to interpret the coefficients as the additional effect of an added photo, video, or GIF.

Comment: Great, I will do that then. Thanks a lot for the help Kevin!

Answer (score 1):

In LOGISTIC REGRESSION you can specify a predictor variable as categorical, and thus make use of a single categorical variable. If you do this, you can specify the type of contrast coding to use and choose which category would be used as the reference category.

The REGRESSION procedure doesn't have facilities for declaring predictors categorical, so if you have an intercept or constant in the model (which of course is the default) and you try to enter K dummy or indicator variables for a K-level categorical variable, one of them will be linearly dependent on the intercept and the other K-1 dummies, and as Kevin said, will be left out.

You may be confused by which one the procedure leaves out. When the default ENTER method is used in REGRESSION, it tries to enter all the independent variables, but does it one variable at a time and performs a tolerance check to avoid numerical problems associated with redundant or nearly redundant variables. The way it does this results in the last predictor specified being the first to enter, and after that, the variable with the smallest absolute correlation with that previously entered variable, then the remaining candidate variable with the least relationship with the two entered already, etc. In cases where there are ties on tolerance values, the later listed variable gets entered.